# How could one apply convolutional neural network on inherently unordered input?

Tags: conv-neural-network

In visual tasks, I would have `(width, height, channel)`. Now imagine I have a bunch of pixels (thus vectors of length `channel`), but there is no inherent ordering to these "pixels".
Let's assume that "patterns" in the "picture" is still informative (for example, particular combinations of these "pixel" could give rise to hierarchical features).
Now, what are some techniques I could apply in this scenario? Naively, I could just take a few of the dimensions in `channel` and pretend they are width and height (as in, order the remaining dimensions of the vectors according to these dimensions and then apply convolution on the result) - has this been done before?

Answer (score 1):

You should use a feed-forward neural network, not a convolutional one. The idea behind neural networks is to work with hierarchical features. The idea behind convolutional neural networks is to find hierarchical features which are translation invariant across the image. Since your pixels are not arranged in any nice ordering, and there is no notion of translation invariance anymore, you must drop the convolutions, and just use a feed-forward network, which is perfectly capable of finding hierarchical features.

The idea you said about choosing features randomly and using them as the x and y axes on an image might work, but it would be very tricky to get right. You would have to somehow discretize those values onto a grid. If you were dead-set on doing this, I suppose you could choose random features to use as x and y and see which two features work best.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Suppose however that my features are embeddings that have good linear substructures (like GloVe vectors). Shouldn't I then expect to find translation invariant features across the hyperspace? Say presence of both of the words "King" and "Man" is informative. I'd imagine a convnet would be able to generalize that to "Queen" and "Woman" - would a feed-forward network also be able to exploit that sort of thing?